# Multibyte error when importing many csv files

Tags: r, csv, import, multibyte

```
Error in type.convert(data[[i]], as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec, na.strings = character(0L)) : 
  invalid multibyte string at '<a7><8a>w<4f>'<86>u3<cc>V'<c6>70?<f2><83><f5><9f><8f><f6>yUe]m   ])TQ<95><94><9d><bb><d9>h<c3><fa>EQ<b4><ae><8a>'
```

I get the above error when trying to import a directory with about 1100 cdv files.  I must have a symbol in one file somewhere, but I have no idea how to find the file that is causing the problem

I am importing using the following code:

```
   file_list <- list.files("directory")
   dataset<- ldply(file_list, read.csv, header=FALSE,
   comment.char="",fill=TRUE,blank.lines.skip=TRUE,quote="")
```

An example file:

```
 ,    11,   2905, - 2905,NE,   1595,LB, ,    11,      ,  ,    ,    0, 6:33A,01MY11,        
 ,    11,   1595, - 1620,NE, -    5,LB, ,    14,      ,  ,    ,    0, 6:36A,01MY11,        
 ,    12,   8565, - 8615,NE,   9030,LB, ,     9,      ,  ,    ,    0, 6:56A,01MY11,        
 ,    12,   5095, - 5095,NE,   3965,LB, ,     8,      ,  ,    ,    0, 6:58A,01MY11,        
 ,    12,   3840, - 3845,NE,     85,LB, ,     4,      ,  ,    ,    0, 7:02A,01MY11,        
 ,    13,   1120, - 1120,NE,  10400,LB, ,     4,      ,  ,    ,    0, 7:18A,01MY11,        
 ,    13,   4835, - 5355,NE,   5465,LB, ,     3,      ,  ,    ,    0, 7:20A,01MY11,        
 ,    13,   5180, - 5180,NE,    275,LB, ,     1,      ,  ,    ,    0, 7:23A,01MY11,        
 ,    13,     30, -   30,NE,    295,LB, ,    13,      ,  ,    ,    0, 7:25A,01MY11,        
 ,    13,    155, -  155,NE,    150,LB, ,    15,      ,  ,    ,    0, 7:26A,01MY11,        
 ,    14,   5210, - 5240,NE,  12265,LB, ,    10,      ,  ,    ,    0, 7:45A,01MY11,        
 ,    14,   4060, - 4065,NE,   8195,LB, ,     7,      ,  ,    ,    0, 7:47A,01MY11,        
 ,    14,   6440, - 6440,NE,   1760,LB, ,     6,      ,  ,    ,    0, 7:50A,01MY11,        
 ,    14,   1790, - 1745,NE,     65,LB, ,    12,      ,  ,    ,    0, 7:52A,01MY11,        
 ,    15,   2340, - 2385,NE,   7345,LB, ,    12,      ,  ,    ,    0, 8:07A,01MY11,        
 ,    15,   4835, - 4835,NE,   2565,LB, ,     5,      ,  ,    ,    0, 8:10A,01MY11,        
 ,    15,   2615, - 2225,NE, -   60,LB, ,     2,      ,  ,    ,    0, 8:12A,01MY11,
```

Any ideas on how to get about 1100 files like this into a single data set?

I am using OS X and R studio 0.97.551.

Comment: If you use a loop, it will be easier to find the problematic file:
`for(f in file_list) read.csv(f,header=FALSE,comment.char="",fill=TRUE,blank.lines.skip=TRUE,quote=""); f`.
Once you have the file, you can find the line containing the invalid character
by playing with the `nrows` argument.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I'm fairly new to R and don't know how to apply this? Can you give an example of how to work the loop in and use nrows

Comment: I get this all the time, almost always because of Windows-1252 encoding. This is a pretty typical problem. You should start by identifying the offending file(s). Vincent provided you with code to loop through the files, the one(s) that it stops on is the one with the problem.